# MVC4 jQueryMobile won't show custom error page OnException

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get a custom error page to display from a MVC4 Mobile Application but keep just getting the "Error Loading Page" yellow message being displayed instead of my custom page.

I have tried using the **HandleErrorAttribute** as below on Actions and Controllers with no success

```
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(SqlException), View = "DatabaseError")]
```

I have also tried overriding the OnException method of my base controller but this also doesn't appear to have any effect.

```
 protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
                base.OnException(filterContext);

            Logger.LogException(filterContext.Exception);

            if (filterContext.Exception is SqlException)
                {
                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "DatabaseError" };
                }

            if (filterContext.Exception is SomeOtherException)
                {
                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error" };
                }

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
                {
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
                }
        }
```

If I try these methods on a non jQueryMobile MVC4 application they work as expected, just not in my mobile application!

Anyone have any insight as to why and how to make this work??

Answer (score 0):

Ok so by disabling Ajax the appropriate error pages now get displayed!

In my _layout.cshtml page I added the following javascript:

```
 $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to check in your filter if the request is via AJAX and return a `JsonResult` instead of a `ViewResult`, something like:

```
public class TypeSwitchingHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    private static readonly string[] AJAX_ACCEPT_TYPES = new[] { "application/json", "application/javascript", "application/xml" };

    private bool IsAjax(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        return filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"
            ||
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.AcceptTypes.ContainsAny(AJAX_ACCEPT_TYPES);
    }

    private void setResult(ExceptionContext filterContext, object content)
    {
        if( IsAjax(filterContext) )
        {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult { Data = content, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        } else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = (string)content };
        }
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        // your code...then where you set the result...
        setResult(filterContext, "DatabaseError etc");
    }
}
```

Then you'd have to interpret the ajax response appropriately on client-side.  You could also send different content if it's an ajax request, like a standard `{success: t/f, message: Exception.Message }` object, and set the response status codes appropriately as well.