# overridden method OnException does not redirect to Error page under shared folder, if exception occurs outside controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, exception, controller

My application is Webforms app but one module alone has been developed in MVC.
In my controller, I have overridden onException like below

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {
    if (Session["User"] != null) {
        string controllerName = string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        string actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        UserInfo user = (UserInfo)Session["User"];
        ExceptionInfo exinfo = new ExceptionInfo() {
            ExceptionDescription = onvert.ToString(filterContext.Exception.Message),
                                ExceptionLayer = filterContext.Exception.StackTrace,
                                Module = this.GetType().Name,
                                UserID = user.UserId,
                                ExceptionDate = System.DateTime.Now,
                                MethodName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
        };
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult() {
            ViewName = "Error",
                                ViewData= new ViewDataDictionary<ExceptionInfo>(exinfo)
        };
    }
}
```

This is working fine if the error occurs in the controller(correctly redirected to Error page in Shared folder under Views. But if an error occurs in DB layer, OnException Method is does get hit, but redirection to Error view is not happening and the same page is displayed.

Need help with knowing why this is happening.

Comment: Guys, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out why my error.aspx was not being called.
Because the exception that I was trying to catch was from a $.ajax method. Even though the method is a part of the controller, it still does not render the error view as the control returns to failure part of the ajax call.
I just had to handle the ajax exception.

Note: even if OnException gets called, if the exception is a result of an ajax call, we surely need to handle it separately.

Cheers and thanks...

Comment: you can also check if the request is ajax (something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/27304584/1037948) and return a `JsonResult` in your error filter.  Note that you have to set the `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode` to an error value as well if you want ajax to route it to the "fail" callback.